# Balls go through the edge of an opening in a cylinder?

Tags: modeling, animation, edges, soft-body

I'm currently working on creating an obstacle course for some soft-body "blob" balls to go through, particularly a shallow "funnel" made from a cylinder. There's a hole in the bottom of the cylinder where the balls fall through, and I want to make it small. However, regardless of how I do that, it looks like the they're falling THROUGH the edge areas around the hole, not landing on it and falling into the hole. I would like to find a way to overcome this problem. Any advice?

Here is the link to the file...
[image]

This is the problem I have...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I would first of all flip the normals of the funnel, because they are pointing with their inside upwards, and you can try enabling _Override Normals_ in the _softbody & Cloth_ settings of the collision objects (which might make flipping the normals obsolete, but I'd do it nevertheless).

Comment: How do you Override Normals? How do you flip the normals of the funnel?

Comment: I tried doing that, but the balls keep going through the edge of the cylinder funnel.

Answer (score 3):

I can’t download the file atm since I’m not home but from previous problems like this an easy solution that tends to work for me is using a solidify modifier on the collision object. So in this case the cylinder.

Comment: I did that, but nothing has changed.